# c# WPF How to change only the content?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Window, and when i press a button("CD" or "Property"), only the content change, not to open another windows form.How can i do that, because the `Show()`, or `ShowDialog()` opens a new window

**[UPDATE]: Solution**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Pane1" Visibility="Visible"/>
<stackPanel x:Name="Pane2" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

and when i press button 1 the Pane1 visibility chane to Collapsed, and the Pane 2 visibility change to Visible

Comment: Without relevant code, it is hard to answer.

Comment: I can't find turoials or someting.

Comment: What do you mean by "content"?

Comment: you can try to inject components in your form

Comment: In Java there are Panels, and in one JFrame you can chane panels.On panels there are different components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your Form to a Control. A form is something that is opened, not embedded onto a window.

You will then want to manage the main form's controls. The most simple way:

```
void OnBtnClick(...)
{
    List<Control> ctrls = new List<Control>(Controls); 

    Controls.Clear();

    foreach(Control ctrl in ctrls )
         ctrl.Dispose();

    Controls.Add(new yourContrl());
}
```

There are better ways of doing this, but from a beginners perspective this will do the job you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the contents of the window on the button's click event. Instead of opening a new form with different controls, you could lay your controls on `Panel`s and set them visible/invisible as needed.

Or you could use a `TabControl` and change the active page on the button's click.

Or you could just create new controls and add/remove them from the form as needed.

The possibilities for doing this are endless: unless you narrow your question, there are infinite ways of doing what you want.

Comment: (well, not really infinite ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can have your information in panels and in click event, you can show and hide these panels to change the form content.